# How to use curl request in JMeter?

Tags: curl, file-upload, jmeter, load-testing

I have such curl command:

```
curl -X POST -T "{sample_data.csv}" -H "Content-Type: text/csv" https://api.mysite.com/v1/jobs/upload.json?key={api_key}
```

The problem is I don't understand in which component in JMeter I should pass `"{sample_data.csv}"` file to upload to the endpoint.

Now I have such configuration:

[image]

When I run test it shows me:

```
"error":{"message":"Un-Acceptable format, Content-Type must be one of those listed in \"formats\" but you sent \"multipart/form-data; boundary=E-VEr1-ZesF7xja5HezBWptB6xP_gsGODn\"","formats":["text/csv","text/plain","application/vnd.ms-excel","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet","application/json","application/xml","application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet"]}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change "Protocol" to `https`
2. Uncheck "Use multipart/form-data for POST"
3. In "Send Files With the Request" click "Add" and provide file location
4. Add [HTTP Header Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to sent "Content-Type" header with the value of "text/csv"

Answer (score 0):

To simulate this curl call with JMeter you'll need:

[HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) configured as follows:

- **Server Name or IP:** anarinsky.aaa.com
- **Protocol:** http
- **Method:** POST
- **Path:** /rest/secure/requestOrderMultipleAttr/skuOrderList/AAA_Prod_Go_d2/quantityAdult/1/quantityChild/1/email/anarinsky@aaa.com
- **Parameters:** **Name:** email **Value:** anarinsky@aaa.com

[HTTP Authorization Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) as a child of HTTP Request (if you want to use username/password only for this HTTP Request) or at the same level if you intend to use it for all requests in scope.

- **Username:** anarinsky@aaa.com
- **Password:** a1234

Adapt your own parameters to this example .

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't resole my problem - passing file like curl -T FILE